# Why is my Ruby on Rails RSpec test passing with both @plugin and @plugins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm in Chapter 10 of the Foundation Rails 2 book. We're working with RSpec.

We're testing the 'index' action of the 'PluginsController'.

Here's the code for the controller:

```
    class PluginsController < ApplicationController
      # GET /plugins
      # GET /plugins.xml
      def index
        @plugins = Plugin.find(:all)

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.xml  { render :xml => @plugins }
        end
      end
```

Here's the code for the tests for that controller:

```
    require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'

describe PluginsController, " GET to /plugins" do

  before do
    @plugin = mock_model(Plugin)
    Plugin.stub!(:find).and_return([@plugin])
  end

  it "should be successful" do
    get :index
    response.should be_success
  end

  it "should find a list of all plugins" do
    Plugin.should_receive(:find).with(:all).and_return([@plugin])
    get :index
  end


  it "should assign the list of plugins to a variable to be used in the view" 


  it "should render the index template" 

end
```

When we were writing our test, I thought that this line

```
Plugin.should_receive(:find).with(:all).and_return([@plugin])
```

should have had

```
@plugins
```

and not

```
@plugin
```

because in the controller we have

```
def index
@plugins = Plugin.find(:all)
```

I wanted to see what would happen if I changed

```
Plugin.should_receive(:find).with(:all).and_return([@plugin])
```

to

```
Plugin.should_receive(:find).with(:all).and_return([@plugins])
```

and the test passed.

So...why is it @plugin and not @plugins? And...why does the test pass with both?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When you have an undefined variable, as @plugins is since you don't define it earlier in the test, it will show up as nil.

What `Plugin.should_receive(:find).with(:all).and_return([@plugins])` actually do in this case is that it tells `Plugin.find(:all)` to return `[nil]`, which according to your test is valid.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thanks, Jimmy.

I'm still wondering, though...in 'PluginsController' we have 

def index
        @plugins = Plugin.find(:all)

so why don't we use @plugins in the test? Why are we using @plugin as in @plugin = mock_model(Plugin)?

Comment: Well, that is up to you. It is just an instance variable used in the tests, so you can choose which name you want. Perhaps a better name would be `@mocked_plugin`. I guess the reason they called it `@plugin` and not `@plugins` in the book is because it is not an array of mocks (only a single instance, thus no plural)